# Is my proof for well-definedness of the Hilbert curve valid?

Tags: analysis, curves

If I want show that the Hilbert-Curve is well-defined, I think that it is sufficient to show, that $(H_n(x))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy-sequence for every $x \in [0,1]$, where $H_n$ is the n-th Hilbert-Polygon.

If I am not wrong, than this property follows directly from the fact, that for any $x \in [0,1]$ the sequence doesn't leave its "square". Take $H_n(x)$, than $H_{n+i}(x), i \in \mathbb{N}$ will be in the same square with sidelength $\frac{1}{2^n}$ where $H_n(x)$ is located.

From here, there are no difficulties to write that down formally. I only wanted to check if my idea/argument is right.

Comment: You are about to show that the point-wise limit exists, i.e., that $H\colon[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$ is a function. Remains to show that $H$ is continuous.

Comment: You are correct. Since all the $H_m(x)$ for $m > n$ are still within the same construction square $S_n$ containing $H_n(x)$, the maximum distance that any of them can be from $H_n(x)$ is $\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2^n}$, which makes $H_n(x)$ a Cauchy sequence.